# Unable to Generate Script for 3 Views in SQL server management studio 2008

Tags: stored-procedures, ssms, sql-server-2008

I have a strange problem

When I create Object Script (script to drop and create Stored Procedures, Views, Functions) from Sql Server 2008 it misses 3 Views don't know why?

I am performing Following steps to create object script

1) Open Sql Server 2008 Management Studio
2) Connect to server
3) Right click on selected database then click on Tasks -> Generate Script, then select database from list, click Next.
4) It gives options I am changing three options i.e. Include If Not Exists = true, Script Drop = true, Script Use Database = false and clicing Next button
4) Now selecting SP, Views and Functions and clicking Next,
5) clicking Select All for All the coming screens
6) Finally clicking Finish button.

Is there any limitation or special condition or convention that I am not following and causing Views not to include in Generate Script?

Please let me know  if I am missing something , I have tried many ways.

I also found that this problem not only exists with Views but it also exists with Functions and Stored Procedures.

If we rename them it works fine , for example a Function earlier named dbo.SeperateElementsInt was working fine, but strangely, Generate Script ignored this function, later we renamed it to dbo.SeperateElementsInteger and it started generating script.

We cannot change the View names as it is used at many places.

Views which are giving problem are dbo.DivisionInfo and dbo.CustomerDivisonOfficeInfo
Stored Procedure which is giving problem is dbo.procsync_get_zVariable

The problem exists with SSMS 2005 too.

Thanks

Comment: Can You script them by right-clicking on view in Object Explorer and selecting Script View as?

Comment: Yes, the problem occurs only when we "Select All" views, if you select 10-15 views including them script will be generated

Comment: Unfortunately, I have no idea other than to turn profiler on and see why doesn't SSMS see those views? At one moment it will have to query INFORMATION_SCHEMA or some other system object to get list of views. And one more thing: check if those 3 views are shown in the list when You do Select All when generating scripts.

Comment: The view information is available in INFORMATION_SCHEMA and these views are also available in list when I do Select All when generating scripts.

Comment: I also found that this problem not only exists with Views but it also exists with Functions and Stored Procedures.

If we rename them it works fine , for example a Function earlier named dbo.SeperateElementsInt was working fine, but strangly, Generate Script ignored this function, later we renamed it to dbo.SeperateElementsInteger and it started generating script.

We cannot change the View names as it is used at many places.

Views which are giving problem are dbo.DivisionInfo and dbo.CustomerDivisonOfficeInfo
StoredProcedure which is giving problem is dbo.procsync_get_zVariable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We didn't understand each other on INFORMATION_SCHEMA-profiler issue. I was suggesting to turn profiler on, because SSMS does a SELECT on INFORMATION_SCHEMA with some where clauses. I suspect that the query itself cuts off your views. Once You have a query that SSMS executes to get the list of objects You should find why it doesn't see some views.

Here are the scripts that SSMS executes when You select all views and start scripting. Check if any of them doesn't return DivisionInfo view. (I've created DivisionInfo view in my database to reproduce your case). For quick check execute them one by one and read my comments after each query. **Please note that You should actually catch queries on your environment with Profiler, because they may differ on your environment.**

Before showing screen to select views, procedures, ... SSMS executes following script to get the list of views:

```
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT
''Server[@Name='' + quotename(CAST(
        serverproperty(N''Servername'')
       AS sysname),'''''''') + '']'' + ''/Database[@Name='' + quotename(db_name(),'''''''') + '']'' + ''/View[@Name='' + quotename(v.name,'''''''') + '' and @Schema='' + quotename(SCHEMA_NAME(v.schema_id),'''''''') + '']'' AS [Urn],
v.name AS [Name],
SCHEMA_NAME(v.schema_id) AS [Schema]
FROM
sys.all_views AS v
WHERE
(v.type = @_msparam_0)and(CAST(
 case 
    when v.is_ms_shipped = 1 then 1
    when (
        select 
            major_id 
        from 
            sys.extended_properties 
        where 
            major_id = v.object_id and 
            minor_id = 0 and 
            class = 1 and 
            name = N''microsoft_database_tools_support'') 
        is not null then 1
    else 0
end          
             AS bit)=0)
ORDER BY
[Schema] ASC,[Name] ASC',N'@_msparam_0 nvarchar(4000)',@_msparam_0=N'V'
```

Is your view listed? You can add condition `WHERE v.name = 'DivisionInfo'` to filter it. If there is no DivisionInfo listed check what part of this query eliminates it from result set.

Once You select objects to script and start scripting, SSMS creates temp table, store objects in it and executes scripts to find related objects.

Create temp table and insert DivisionInfo view in it:

CREATE TABLE #tempdep (objid int NOT NULL, objname sysname NOT NULL, objschema sysname NULL, objdb sysname NOT NULL, objtype smallint NOT NULL)

```
exec sp_executesql N'INSERT INTO #tempdep 

SELECT
v.object_id AS [ID],
v.name AS [Name],
SCHEMA_NAME(v.schema_id) AS [Schema],
db_name(),
2
FROM
sys.all_views AS v
WHERE
(v.type = @_msparam_0)and(v.name=@_msparam_1 and SCHEMA_NAME(v.schema_id)=@_msparam_2)',N'@_msparam_0 nvarchar(4000),@_msparam_1 nvarchar(4000),@_msparam_2 nvarchar(4000)',@_msparam_0=N'V',@_msparam_1=N'DivisionInfo',@_msparam_2=N'dbo'
```

Did this query insert anything in #tempdep? If not, check why. **Once again, You have to use Profiler to get queries from your environment instead of using queries I put here because they are from my environment.**

When You start profiling, there should be many inserts like the one above. You need to find the one that relates to DivisionInfo. You can use Find option to find it because You will see many queries in Profiler because You have a lot of other views. To make profiler log smaller, script only views.

As You can see, idea is to start profiling and start scripting. Once scripting is finished, stop profiler and check scripts executed by SSMS. You should find why it doesn't see DivisionInfo. If there is no DivisionInfo in profiler log but You can check it for scripting in wizard, then take scripts for DivisionInfo and for one view that scripting works for and see the differences between them. Take a close look at differences between them in regards to scripts that SMSS uses to retrieve them.

- for some reason SSMS discards this view
- according to data he extracted with queries (catched from profiler)

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into the exact issue.  We were trying to script out the schema of one database (Call it Database_A) and many views wouldn't script out.

We'd decommissioned another database (Call it Database_B) and all the views that wouldn't script (in Database_A) pointed out to that database (Database_B) - which was accessed through a linked server, and was offline.  Since all the connection strings were now pointing to the new server that Database_A was now on, I brought Database_A on the old server online in read_only for just long enough to script out the views, and it worked.  Took the database offline again, and we had what we needed.

The script I threw together to find the linked server reference in the views was this:

```
    use Database_B
    go

    select so.name, sc.text 
    from sysobjects so, syscomments sc
    where so.id = sc.id
    and sc.text like '%Database_A%'
```

That's what worked for me, I hope it works for you as well.

Take care,

Tom